# StackExchange stats and rounding discrepancies

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, statistics, stackexchange.com

I am referring to [these stats](https://stackexchange.com/sites?sort=newest).

As an example, I'll take the number of users. You will see that there are ten sites for which the number of users is displayed as "1k". However, if you hover over those numbers, you will find out that the actual values vary wildly:

- 1,183
- 1,217
- 1,304
- 1,321
- 1,326
- 1,412
- 1,714
- 1,849
- 1,948
- 1,987

I find this somewhat irritating, because over at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), rounding works differently. If a site has 1,987 users, the number is rounded *up* to 2k rather than *down* to 1k. Also, on SE sites themselves, if a question had 1,987 views, they would be rounded up, not down.

Is there a particular reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: Looks like the first set of data gets truncated, while the rest are actually rounded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good catch.  We're now rounding correctly and, as an added bonus, I threw in an extra decimal point of precision to single-digit numbers, so it'll show "1.1k" now instead of "1k".