# Are statistics rounded up or down on All Sites?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, statistics, rounding

On [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), these statistics are displayed: questions, answers, percentage answered, users, visits/day, questions/day and age.

Are these rounded up, rounded down, or just normally rounded?

Comment: related: [StackExchange stats and rounding discrepancies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64906/stackexchange-stats-and-rounding-discrepancies) The answer is "rounded up" There's bound to be a post somewhere, it's a typical nerd thing to ask but I couldn't find it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StackExchange stats and rounding discrepancies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64906/stackexchange-stats-and-rounding-discrepancies)

Comment: @PolyGeo is that the one? I thought there'd be a better "original".

Comment: @PolyGeo no, that’s not a dupe. That one’s pointing out problems, while this is asking how it’s **supposed** to work.

Comment: The answer to that says "we're now rounding correctly", which to me implies that it's using standard rounding rules. That said, it would be nice if this were confirmed through actual testing, so I'm moving to leave this open.

Comment: I would vote to re-open if this question showed awareness of the duplicate, and evidence that something other than standard rounding rules appeared to be in use.

Comment: Stormblessed, as an interesting related note, there's a Wiki for [how these calculations are made for Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294558/282094).